# How to add this JQuery Accordion to Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Below this is a jQuery accordion

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24708866/labs/jquery-multi-open-accordion/index.html

I want to add this to a Wordpress Site Page.

And want to load only to a particular page, so the ***jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js*** and ***jQuery.multi-accordion-1.5.3.js*** will not load to other post or pages.

I do not want to use any plugins is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hare Krishna,

Do Like this

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery-1.3.2.min', 'wp-content/themes/xyz/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script('custom', 'wp-content/themes/xyz/js/accordion.js'); ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

**or e.g. you can do like this**

```
if( is_page('x')) { ?>
// YOUR SCRIPT STUFF
<?php }
```

**Also check your theme function.php file if these are exists then you have done**

```
function scripts() {
if ( !is_admin() ) { // this if statement will insure the following code only gets added to your wp site and not the admin page cause your code has no business in the admin page right unless that's your intentions
// jquery
    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); // this deregisters the current jquery included in wordpress
    wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"), false); // this registers the replacement jquery
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // you can either let wp insert this for you or just delete this and add it directly to your template
// your own script
    wp_register_script('yourscript', ( get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/yourscript.js'), false); //first register your custom script
    wp_enqueue_script('swfobject'); // then let wp insert it for you or just delete this and add it directly to your template
    // just in case your also interested
    wp_register_script('yourJqueryScript', ( get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/yourJquery.js'), array('jquery')); // this last part-( array('jquery') )is added in case your script needs to be included after jquery
    wp_enqueue_script('yourJqueryScript'); // then print. it will be added after jquery is added
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'scripts'); // now just run the function
```

**So finally you can do like this**

```
<?php
function load_index_page(){
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-1.3.2.min', 'wp-content/themes/xyz/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('easySlider1.5', 'wp-content/themes/xyz/js/accordion.js');
}?>

<?php if (is_home()){
    add_action('init', load_index_page);
} ?>

<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - You should call your jQuery scripts into header.php

2 - Then specify if is pageid into that same php file.  Call your functions if page id is correct.

3 - Type the correct html code in the content of the page

note : make sure your html code is loaded before you call your jquery function.

Et Voilà !

Comment: Thank you DAV Just nearer to this 

 <?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>

<?php wp_head(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/js/accordion.js"></script>
</head>

But Please do let me know how to specify pageid and to call my function if page id is correct??